# Reviewing has become harder

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, user-interface

Is it just me or has reviewing become harder with the changed interface? It now takes two clicks where I'm sure it used to take only one. Not a lot of difference perhaps, but enough to put me off. I've tried it but the new process does nothing for me, and I've now pretty much abandoned review queues.

A button for each of "I'm done", "No action needed" or "Skip" would be most efficient. Oh, though wasn't that how it used to be, so perhaps someone will point me to the reasons behind the change.

Comment: I think this is the one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues

Comment: This also came up: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363552/workflow-changes-for-review-queues

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks. Unfortunately if it's harder to use then people like you (i.e. moderators) are likely to end up with a larger queue of work. Have you noticed any queue lengthening or am I just worrying about a problem that doesn't really exist?

Comment: I'm also not a fan of the extra clicks, but the UI is not up to us. I suppose if the UI team finds that posts ["are not acted upon"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363552/307535), then they'll "ensure posts get the attention they need in a timely manner" at which point maybe they'll consider feedback from the reviewing community who say **could you please make the job easier?**

Comment: @JeffSchaller apparently feedback on that post ended a fortnight ago (28 April). I'll leave a comment there but I doubt as a lone voice I'll be heard. And as I say, maybe it's just me anyway

Comment: ditto I find it harder to use as well.

Comment: Committee-syndrome happened by the company.